How do I remove any text between parentheses, including the parentheses themselves?
I have a string in a table column that I want to remove the parentheses and their contents from. I'm working in Presto/Trino SQL.
Example string:
'apple not found for (1) tree on farm (123) on highway (99).'

Desired output:
'apple not found for tree on farm on highway .'

Pretend query is currently:
select 
applestring
from appletable


Presumably nested parens isn't a concern?

I'd do it in a more precise manner:
Fixing what @Cary Swoveland pointed me to:
You want to remove all occurrences of:

a space, 0 or 1 times (?)
an open parenthesis (escape that with a backslash as the parenthesis has a special meaning in regex-es
a digit (\d), one or more times (+)
a close parenthesis (escape that with a backslash as the parenthesis has a special meaning in regex-es

So you just supply the pattern to be replaced as the second argument, and supply no replacement string or expression.
Because I'm sometimes a bean counter and @Cary Swoveland's example triggers it, I finally remove the leading space left by the REGEXP_REPLACE() call with a TRIM() function:
WITH
appletable(applestring) AS (
            SELECT 'apple not found for (1) tree on farm (123) on highway (99).'
  UNION ALL SELECT '(123) should be outahere'
)
SELECT
  TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(applestring,' ?\(\d+\)')) AS replacement
FROM appletable;




replacement




apple not found for tree on farm on highway.


should be outahere




Right you are, @Cary Swoveland. I'll fix that one.

No need for attribution in the answer. Better, imo, is just to quietly edit your answer, containing no mention of it being changed. Think of it as writing part of a book, which may undergo multiple edits, none of which make mention of an edit. Consider also using regex101.com, including several string examples, and providing a link to it in your answer.

What was useful was:
select 
regexp_replace(applestring, '\(.*?\)', '') as applestring
from appletable


Instead of .*? you can also just look for a series of anything other than a close parenthesis [^)]+

@jmcgriz .*? and [^)]+ are not equivalent, () is matched for the first but not yours, you'd need to still use *

True, it didn't seem like () was a use case from the question, but yes if you need to match that it would require \([^)]*\)
